# On the probability of no. of radiating particles

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider an experiment that consists of counting the number of $\beta $ particles
given of in one second time interval by one gram of a radio active material.
It is known that, on the average, 3.2 $\beta$-particles are given off .

What is
a good approximation to the probability that no more than 2 such $\beta$-
particles appear?

I don't know where to start with this problem. How does one calculate the probability that between $x$ particles are given  off ?  (I hope this makes sense )

Please help . thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the nature of radioactive decays, in which the probability for an atom to decay in a short time interval is constant, and that there are an enormous number of atoms to decay (1 gram), the random variable that represents the total number of atoms that decay in a fixed time interval follows the Poisson distribution. Use that distribution to work out the probability that 0, 1, or 2 decays occur in one second, given that the expectation value is 3.2.